# Add component dynamically with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, components

i would like to know is there a way to add component dynamically because what i want to do:
When i click on my button it trigger a function which add in my html a new selector with those property:

```
 <select ng-change="test(selectedId)" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="id.id as id.pseudo for id in idList"> </select>
```

and the button:

```
<button ng-click="addSelector()">add selector</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your controller should define a click handler like this:

```
   $scope.idList = ['first element', 'second element'];
   $scope.addSelector = function(){
     $scope.idList.push('new element');
   }
```